# Using own login authenticate handler a good practice?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, security

I have used my own custom user handler to authenticate user's.

```
    protected void Login1_Authenticate1(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
            {
            SqlReader rdr=null;
            rdr=GetReader(Login1.UserName.ToString().ToLower().Trim(),Login1.Password);
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                e.Authenticated = true;
                Session["Username"] = Login1.UserName.ToString();
                Session["Name"] = rdr[0].ToString() + " " + (rdr[1].ToString() == null ? "" : rdr[1]);
                id = rdr[2].ToString();
                }
            }
```

For all other parts of the website I check if Session["Username"] is not null. My question is using the above method of authentication and storing username in a Session a bad Idea? I heard session's can be hacked but aren't they encrypted and hashed? If they are not hashed, how can we hash them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using forms authentication because of few reasons:

1. Forms authentication has been developed by microsoft in many years. Its tested its safe. My method has never been tested, so neither you nor I can be sure if its safe or not but forms authentication is trusted by all.
2. People struggle a lot with Sessions expiring before time.
3. With many simultaneous users accessing your website, using a session will lead to memory issues.
4. Using forms authentication is cleaner and more elegant.
5. Why not use a approach which many developers use, if tomorrow someone joins your team and helps in your project, he may get your logic wrong and may compromise security.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong is using a custom user handler. I hope your `GetReader` function is safe from sql-injection and other web based attacks.

If you are not sure, consider using [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

The `while` loop seems unnecessary, won't you be getting only one record? You don't need to loop.

You don't need to check if a `Session["Username"]` is not null to be sure a user is logged in. Is a user accesses that page directly, without a login, he will be carried to the login page.

Comment: No he does not get redirected if not set in webconfig. One will have to set it in weconfig or check Session value on pageload and if not present redirect the user to login page

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a very basic and probably insecure. Also sessions can lead to high memory usage if your website goes big, as well as difficulty in scaling to multiple servers.

I have a second option for you rather than using Forms Authentication though.

I suspect you made your own authentication handler because Forms Authentication is really quite a bit of a pain to setup and customize.

Well, I wrote my own authentication module called FSCAuth. It's available at [binpress](http://www.binpress.com/app/fscauth/231) It's BSD licensed. It's designed to be simple, secure, and stay out of your way. It revolves around a very minimal `UserStore` as an interface to your database. It can use just about any Database format imaginable. After it's setup, for authorization all that must be done is `Authentication.RequiresLogin()` to enforce that a portion of a page requires authentication. It handles the redirect business and such, you just provide it with a login page and a not-authorized page. It also is secure out of the box, and does not make use of sessions or temporary tables in a database. It is "stateless".

Also along with being (in my opinion) awesome out of the box, because it's BSD licensed, it can be a great starting point for your own authentication system